# can't logout from ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-local-storage

Hi I have an issue with ionic login and logout.

Each time after logout, i can still click the back button and it will bring me back to my previous page. may i know how to clear or delete session when logout so that user unable to go back to previous page from the login?

```
var default_stat;
$scope.logout = function(){
    $ionicLoading.show({template:'Logging out....'});
    $localstorage.set('loggin_state', '');
    $state.go('login');
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
    $ionicHistory.clearCache();
};
```

during login i use localstorage to indicate user has logged in

```
$localstorage.set('loggin_state', '1');
```

Comment: I have the same problem, it does not clear the cache or history. I read in docs that $ionicHistory will only clear the cache of all the other views except the view you are currently on. I need answer to this same question.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841166/reset-unload-controller-after-changestate-logout-called-angularjs

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
$scope.logout = function(){
    $ionicLoading.show({template:'Logging out....'});
    $localstorage.set('loggin_state', '');

    $timeout(function () {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $ionicHistory.clearCache();
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({ disableBack: true, historyRoot: true });
        $state.go('login');
        }, 30);

};
```

I've found out that adding a little delay allow `$ionicHistory` to clear the cache.

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({ disableBack: true, historyRoot: true });
```

- **disableBack**: The next view should forget its back view, and set it to null.
- **historyRoot**: The next view should become the root view in its history stack.

Answer (score 5):

`$ionicHistory.clearCache()` now returns promise so you can ensure cache is cleared. So you can call like this:

```
$ionicHistory.clearCache().then(function() {
    //now you can clear history or goto another state if you need
    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({ disableBack: true, historyRoot: true });
    $state.go('login');
})
```

There is no need for the above timeout like things.

[credit goes to](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/pull/3724)

Answer (score 2):

This is because `ionic` is caching the view, So that will stop ionic going through the controller.

So you could bust the cache as follows

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="My Title!">
  ...
</ion-view>
```

[read here for more](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/)